# cannot login with with ad credentials

Tags: windows-7, login, active-directory, smartcard

I cannot login on my laptop with my AD account, only with my smart card. This happened only after I changed my AD account password.

If i lock my laptop while I'm logged with my smart card, I can unlock it with my AD account. Only then it works.

What can I do to login with my AD account

Comment: "I cannot login on my laptop with my AD account" What error message are you given when you try?  Have you tried changing your AD password again?

Comment: I changed the AD password already, and the error I get is wrong user name/password

Comment: Does it do this every time you logout or reboot the computer? does it work as expected when other users attempt to log into the computer?  Are you on a wired or wireless connection to the domain controller? Are you _sure_ you numlock or caps lock isn't on when you first go to log in via the keyboard?  Perhaps next time, turn on the on-screen keyboard to confirm that, and what you're typing (as you type it).

Comment: this happens every time i start my laptop, and i'm the only one who logs on it

Comment: is there any way to force windows to store my credentials or to clear the old ones?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a stored credential with your old password in Credential Manager.

Comment: already tried that, i've deleted all stored credentials